# How do I insert autogenerated IDs into association table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am trying to write an app that scrapes recipe and ingredient information from various cooking websites. It almost works how I want it to in that I can successfully insert the recipe into the Recipe table and the ingredients into the Ingredient table, but I have not been able to populate the association table.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for most of my project, but it doesn't demonstrate how to insert into the association table.

I only created a controller for Recipe where the Create function accepts the URL of the recipe you want. I don't want to be able to manipulate data from the Ingredient table directly, so I didn't create a controller for it.

I created three model classes: Recipe, Ingredient, and the association table RecipeIngredient. There is a one-to-many relationship between Recipe and RecipeIngredient as well as a one-to-many relationship between Ingredient and RecipeIngredient.

These are my models:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeIngredient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
}
```

This is my DbContext:

```
public class RecipeListContext : DbContext
{
    public RecipeListContext() : base("RecipeListContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

This is the relevant code from my controller:

```
public class RecipesController : Controller
{
    private RecipeListContext db = new RecipeListContext();

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "URL")] Recipe recipe)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();
            RecipeIngredient recipeIngredient = new RecipeIngredient();

            var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = htmlWeb.Load(recipe.URL);

            //This is the route to the recipe and ingredients for 
            //allrecipes.com
            var recipeName = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1[@class='recipe-summary__h1']");
            var ingredients = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@itemprop='ingredients']");

            //I populate the Name and DateTimeCreated fields for Recipe here
            recipe.Name = recipeName[0].InnerText;
            recipe.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now;

            db.Recipes.Add(recipe);
            db.SaveChanges();

            for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.Count; i++)
            {
                ingredient.Name = ingredients[i].InnerText;
                ingredient.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
                db.Ingredients.Add(ingredient);
                db.SaveChanges();

                //Here I tried to populate the RecipeIngredient object with 
                //the ID from the Ingredient object, but since that ID gets 
                //created in the database upon insertion, ingredient.ID is 
                //just null. I'm not sure how to access this ID in order to 
                //insert it into RecipeIngredient and I'm not even sure if 
                //this is the right (or best) approach to this problem.

                //recipeIngredient.RecipeID = recipe.ID;
                //recipeIngredient.IngredientID = ingredient.ID;
                //db.RecipeIngredients.Add(recipeIngredient);
                //db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(recipe);
    }
```

Is there some function in Entity Framework that will allow me to populate the association table using the autogenerated IDs that were created from the inserts into the two main tables? Or is there another solution?

EDIT:
There were three problems that prevented my application from working as intended.

1. I needed to uncomment the code that assigns the ingredient.ID and recipe.ID to the recipeIngredient foreign keys.
2. I needed to instantiate the recipe and ingredient objects inside of the for loop so that they would reinitialize at the beginning of each pass of the for loop. I was receiving a referential integrity error without them being reinitialized.
3. I needed to populate the DateTimeCreated field in recipeIngredients. I had forgotten to do so and this was causing a dataType mismatch error in the database as a null value translates into 01/01/0001 or something similar which is out of the range of dates that DateTime supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were three problems that prevented my application from working as intended.

1. I needed to uncomment the code that assigns the ingredient.ID and recipe.ID to the recipeIngredient foreign keys.
2. I needed to instantiate the recipe and ingredient objects inside of the for loop so that they would reinitialize at the beginning of each pass of the for loop. I was receiving a referential integrity error without them being reinitialized.
3. Populated the DateTimeCreated field in RecipeIngredients as I had forgotten to do so previously.

My updated and working code is as follows:

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "URL")] Recipe recipe)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = htmlWeb.Load(recipe.URL);

            var recipeName = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1[@class='recipe-summary__h1']");
            var ingredients = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@itemprop='ingredients']");

            recipe.Name = recipeName[0].InnerText;
            recipe.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now;

            db.Recipes.Add(recipe);
            db.SaveChanges();

            for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.Count; i++)
            {
                //Moved these next two lines into the for loop
                Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();
                RecipeIngredient recipeIngredient = new RecipeIngredient();

                ingredient.Name = ingredients[i].InnerText;
                ingredient.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
                db.Ingredients.Add(ingredient);
                db.SaveChanges();

                //uncommented this code
                recipeIngredient.RecipeID = recipe.ID;
                recipeIngredient.IngredientID = ingredient.ID;
                //populated the DateTimeCreated field as I had forgotten
                //to do so already
                recipeIngredient.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
                db.RecipeIngredients.Add(recipeIngredient);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(recipe);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe EF should update your entity object with the identity:

Try this

```
db.Recipes.Add(recipe);
db.SaveChanges();
int newPK = recipe.ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This ended up being part of the problem. There were two additional issues that I found that needed to be fixed before my program would work. I added my solution to the comments.